# Anisotropic kernel of groups of type A

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, central-simple-algebras

I'm studying the results of classification of reductive groups using Tits index and anisotropic kernel.

It is known that simple groups with Tits index $^1 A_{n,r}^{(d)}$ are of the form $SL_{r+1}(D)$, where $D$ is a central division $k$-algebra of degree $d$.

I am suffering to imagine what the semisimple anisotropic kernel of this group should be.
I would appreciate it if someone help me get the answer or a reference on anisotropic kernels of various types (other than just $^1 A_{n,r}^{(d)}$).

Comment: My guess is $(SL_1(D))^{r+1}$.